# Wi-Fi indicator disappearing when iPad connects to Macbook over usb

Tags: macos, wifi

When I connect my iPad Pro to my Macbook Pro using a usb cable, for some reason the iPad loses its wifi connection.
Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

I tried to setup shared internet to fix this issue, but it does not help.

[image]

Comment: What have you already tried to fix the issue yourself?

Comment: Also add the version of macOS and iPadOS on these devices to your original question, please

Comment: @SteveChambers and fab - this is pretty easy to answer. The screen image details exactly what’s happening - this is how Apple allows the mac to take over the network so you can develop or run on Ethernet networking or at least get the devices connected off WiFi or cellular when they are tethered physically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings you show will indeed shut off networking on the iPad when you connect it since the Mac is telling the iPad to get network over the USB cable.

You would disable the iPad USB check box or disable internet sharing altogether so that the iPad doesn’t change network settings next time you plug it in to that specific mac.